# Why does MonoGame Ignores a 3D Model that I added to the contents of the project?

Tags: c#, monogame, 3d-modelling

Hello I try to add a 3D model to my project but I cant get it to work
[SolutionPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vQnd.png)

I try to run the build but I get an exception
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcPkz.png)
any Idea how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Where is the file named in the exception actually located ? What happens if you would put your file in the place the exception indicates ? Also check properties of it in Visual Studio. When you click "part of Build" or "always copy" the file would be copied near your executable.

Comment: Could you scroll down on the exception. and post the relevant code and mgcb file text. Manually copying the .XNB file to the target directory would resolve the issue, but not the root cause.

Comment: After looking online and asking other people I had to Recreate my project... (The ignored files resolved) but even after that I cant load my Model to the project because I get a content load Exception and the Monogame cant find my files even that i added them through contents and rebuild the project